# Does a notion of a context-free complete language exist?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free, reference-request

Is there a notion of a context-free complete language (in the analogous sense to a $NP$-complete language)?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Lautemann and Schwentick prove that Greibach's "hardest context-free grammar" with a neutral symbol is complete for $LOGCFL$ and hence $CFL$ also, under quantifier-free projection without BIT.

This is Corollary 4.3 in their [paper](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.35.6051%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwjLxvK9s7XeAhWUH3AKHUHaDpEQFjADegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2KaKv1Bqufglv-dZ5zd-7P)